# cx-Freeze error while importing reportLab

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, reportlab

in my python3.3 code i am using the reportLab-3.1.44 for pdf generation..

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
```

I am using cx_Freeze 4.3.1 and getting the error as shown in image..but if i remove the reportLab it works fine... 
How should i handle reportLab in my cx_freeze code...
whether `includes=['reportLab'] or import reportLab or include_files=['reportLab']`....
any suggestions on it

[image: screenshot]

since i didn't have 10 reputations my error message is uploaded on another link...its not a malware sir...

Comment: Try using `packages=['reportlab']` in the cx_Freeze setup file. An important part of the error is beyond the bottom of the screen. If you can't see it, when the error comes up, press Ctrl-C and it should copy it as text. Then you can paste it somewhere like https://gist.github.com/

Comment: thanx but even after adding as packages=['reportlab'] in cx_freeze, error remains the same. i am pasting the error at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8db087ac4b1df62b97d8

Comment: seems as if some error in reportlab.platypus ?

Comment: OK, the final error is just because tkinter is trying to write to stderr and there is no stderr. The error before that looks familiar, and I think it might be a mismatch between the Python you're running and the one cx_Freeze is built with. I'd try upgrading to the latest Python (3.4.3) and the latest cx_Freeze (4.3.4, in a pleasing symmetry).

Comment: @ThomasK but if i remove  repotlab from code and don't generate pdf it works fine with python3.3 and cx_freeze 4.3.1.. infact i also installed cx_Freeze version 4.3.3 some time back so now both versions are existing .. still my file gets complied and creates exe.. however only when i want pdf generation and i use reportlab, this error comes in ??

Comment: i checkup with python 3.3.5 and cx_freeze 4.3.3... error remains the same ....kindly assist@ThomasK

Comment: Can you not upgrade to the latest versions? I think this is a bug that has been fixed, but I forget when.

Answer (score 1):

All credit to @ThomasK: Adding `build_exe_options = {"packages": ["reportlab"]}` to my setup.py file worked a treat.

(Note I'm using Python 3.5.2 & cxfreeze 5.0)

Answer (score 0):

cx_Freeze does not recognize Reportlab because the folder in which Reportlab is installed is different from the folder in which it searches. I changed the Reportlab installation folder and put it in the same folder where the cx_Freeze files were and it worked for me